# Can the EM field self-interact in the Standard Model?

Tags: electromagnetism, standard-model, interactions, electroweak

Since the EM field is a linear combination of the electroweak $U(1)$ gauge field and one of the $SU(2)$ gauge fields, does this mean that it has self-interaction terms carried over from the electroweak $SU(2)$ kinetic term?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a term involving two factors of $A_\mu$ (the EM gauge field) and two factors of $W_\mu$ (the charged weak bosons). The Feynman diagram, as usually drawn, has four wavy lines meeting at a point; two of the lines are photons, and two are $W$-bosons. This Feynman diagram is shown in figure/equation (60) on page 12 in

- "A resource for signs and Feynman diagrams of the Standard Model," https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.6213.

For a source that writes out all the messy terms in the Lagrangian in terms of the $A_\mu$ gauge field and the $Z$ and $W$ gauge bosons, see equation (5.169) on page 249 in Renton's book *Electroweak Interactions*. The corresponding Feynman diagram is shown on page 574 in the same book.

However, there is no term involving more than two factors of the $A_\mu$ gauge field itself (no three-photon Feynman diagrams), which is what we usually mean by "self-interaction." So in that sense, the answer is no.

Comment: I would say that "self-interaction" would be a term that exists like $(A_\mu)^n$ where the indices are contracted with some non dynamical Lorentz index.. But such a term would break gauge invariance. So personally I would have said no. But that just comes down to how we're defining self-interaction.

Comment: @InertialObserver I agree. I edited the answer shortly before you posted this comment, just seconds after I posted the original answer (which I quickly realized was "wrong").  :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Makes sense now that I look at all the Electroweak interactions; no gauge field appears more than twice in any. I think one could probably show this from the Lagrangian itself through some structure constant considerations.